# List within data record empty

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.0

i have this class which contains a list of the object ConversieDetail

```
public class ConversieRun
{
    [Key]
    public String Guid { get; set; }
    public String Naam { get; set; }
    public String Status { get; set; }
    public DateTime Start { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Einde { get; set; }
    public List<ConversieDetails> Details { get; set; }
}
```

With the following method i need to return a list of ConversieRun including the ConversieDetails

```
public List<PGData.ConversieRun> GetAll()
{
      //var result = _context.CoversieDetails.ToList();
      return _context.ConversieRun.ToList();
 }
```

however when i return with above example the conversieDetail List is null.
now when i uncomment the result list, the List of conversieDetails will be filled in the ConversieRun object as expected.

any reason why the list of ConversieDetails is null if i don't get them first in another list?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Read about lazy loading here : http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/lazyloading-in-entity-framework.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Relationships in entities are not loaded by default and will be null. You can explicitly tell EF to also load the related entities by using the `Include` like this:

```
_context.ConversieRun.Include(x => x.Details).ToList();
```

Now all `ConversieRun` entities will be loaded including their details.

You can read more about this in the "Loading Related Data" section of the documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data)

The example here is using the Explicit loading method, you can also choose to use the Lazy loading method where the related entities are loaded when you request them. This can however have a negative impact on the number of database queries as it would run a separate query for every `ConversieRun` entity to get its details.